# Where can I access Hold, Manipulation, Navigation events in Mixed Reality Toolkit 2.1?

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, hololens, windows-mixed-reality

I recently updated the HoloLens Toolkit to the new Mixed Reality Toolkit 2.1 in Unity, and now I am missing the interfaces for **Hold**, **Manipulation** and **Navigation**. Were these interfaces (names: "IHoldHandler", "IManipulationHandler", "INavigationHandler") removed, have their names been replaced or entirely replaced with something different?

I had some objects which had different behaviors for hold and manipulation/navigation. I found the interface "**IMixedRealityPointerHandler**", with which I should be able to reproduce the previous behaviors by using the Vectors to measure distance moved away from the original point. But before I do that, I'd like to be sure I am not missing something important, especially given the potential upgrade to hand input with HoloLens 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IHolderHandler → IMixedRealityGestureHandler
IManipulationHandler →  IMixedRealityGestureHandler
INavigationHandler → IMixedRealityGestureHandler

There is a [porting guide](https://microsoft.github.io/MixedRealityToolkit-Unity/Documentation/HTKToMRTKPortingGuide.html) for upgrading from htk to mrtk v2.